# Confused by this unless statement in rubykoans

Tags: ruby

Lines 4 & 5 are causing me grief:

```
1  def test_break_statement
2     i = 1
3     result = 1
4     while true
5       break unless i <= 10
6       result = result * i
7       i += 1
8     end
9     assert_equal 3628800, result
10  end
```

I'm not sure what needs to remain true in the `while true` statement, however I believe it is the code that follows it.  This leads to further confusion because I am reading the line:

`break unless i <= 10` as break if `i` is not smaller or equal to 10.  What procedure is this code going through ie how does the while and break statements interplay.  I think I am nearly there but can't put the process in my head.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while` statements test whatever comes after the word `while.`   If the expression that follows them is `true` they execute the code within the loop.  If the expression is false, they do not.

Thus, as other posters have pointed out, `while true` will always execute the code within the loop.  Luckily for your code there is a `break` statement within the loop.  If there wasn't, the loop would run forever and you'd have to kill the process running your program.

In your code sample the `break` keyword is followed by `unless` which means that it will `break` the loop `unless` the expression following it is true.  Your code will break out of the loop when i is greater than 10.

Answer (score 3):

The code will break out of the endless while loop when i is greater than 10.
But I'm not sure why the condition isn't checked in the while statement.

**Edit:** Had I read the method name I would have understood why the condition isn't checked directly with the while statement. The method's purpose is to test the break statement.

Answer (score 2):

`while true` is an infinite loop. `break`, when executed, will exit it immediately, to continue with the first line after it (`assert_equal...`).

In this specific case (nothing intervening between `while` and `break unless`), it is equivalent to this:

```
 while i <= 10
   result = result * i
   i += 1
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

- `while true` it is endless loop.
- `break unless i <= 10` is same as `break if i > 10` it will break that loop if `i` is smaller or equal to `10`

Comment: 'break unless i <= 10 is same as break if i >= 10', no it's the same as `break if i > 10`. The negation of `<=` is `>`, not `>=`.

Comment: Haven't noticed, that I have typo. Thank you! Also it is good tip.